# Removing strings from array C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

Is there a function to remove the last cell from array?

it's a string array like: `{"a","b","c",""}`.

Comment: An array can contain any objects/types. So please bring a little more sense to your question. Ideally provide an example of input array and required output array. And even better: show what you have tried so far to tackle the problem that didn't work. In simple words: [Ask a question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The length of an array is immutable, but you can create a new array without the empty `""` strings:

```
string[] newArray = myArray.Where(str => str != "").ToArray();
```

Answer (score 9):

Erm... just resize it

```
 Array.Resize(ref theArray, theArray.Length -1);
```

From the docs

> public static void Resize(ref T[] array, int newSize)

Answer (score 6):

If it's an array of strings, you can do something like:

```
 string[] results = theArray.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(s)).ToArray();
```

If you are just going to iterate the results, there's no need to convert back into an array, and you can leave off the `.ToArray()` at the end.

---

Edit:

If you just want to remove the last cell, and not empty entries (as suggested by your edited version), you can do this using [Array.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1.aspx) more efficiently than using the LINQ statement above:

```
  string[] results = new string[theArray.Length - 1];
  Array.Copy( theArray, results, results.Length );
```

Answer (score 5):

An array is a fixed-size collection object.  That makes it woefully inadequate for what you want to do.  The best you could do is create *another* one with one less element.  That's expensive.

Fix the real problem, this should be a `List<string>`, now it's simple.

Answer (score 2):

```
var newArraySize = oldArray.Length - 1;
var newArray = new string[newArraySize];
Array.Copy(oldArray, newArray, newArraySize);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create new array equal to existing array size -1
2. aNewArray = aOldArray

Ofcourse you could just null the last element in your array, but that would result in problems later. Otherwise, use a nice flexible list.

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to get rid of the last element,

```
        int[] a = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        int[] b = new int[a.Length - 1];
        Array.Copy(a, b, a.Length - 1);
```